# SESSION variable Not updated

Tags: php, session

I have A SESSION variable $_SESSION['lang'] and after the first value assigned to it it can not update with another value.

Unfortunately this works well on my localhost but not on the remote server.

```
/////selectlang.php file
if(empty($err)) {
        session_start();

        unset($_SESSION['lang']);

        $_SESSION['lang'] = "";

        $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;

   }


//////Calling form
if (isset($_SESSION['lang']))
{
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}else
{
    $lang = 'locale_en';
}

 require_once ("lang/".$lang.".php");

    echo '<table border="0" width="100%"><tr><td>';
        echo "<font class=fontselectlanguage>".CHOOSE_LANGUAGE;

        echo '<td><form action="/selectlang2" method="post">
            <Select name="lang" />
            <Option class="fontselectlanguage_option" value="locale_en" SELECTED>English</Option>
            <Option class="fontselectlanguage_option" value="locale_vd">Vindu</Option>
    </form>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: how are you storing the session, file / db, if file where are they stored, do you have permissions to create/modify/delete files from that directory? also as @pekka says, Show us some code please.

Comment: Can you show where exactly it fails? Also, you are aware that if `$err` isn't empty, the session doesn't get initialized?

Comment: It doesn't fail. it just refreshes and the old contents of the SESSION variable will still be there. But when you destroy SESSION, it will accept a value and will not accept any other value again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`session_start();` this should be called in all cases towards top of page

so first line of your code should be

```
session_start();
/////selectlang.php file
if(empty($err)) {
```